ios Expo Camera takePictureAsync got 'Received 1 arguments, but 2 was expected' error
Minimal reproducible example
https://snack.expo.dev/@ayseboogie/take-photo-ex
What platform(s) does this occur on?
iOS
Did you reproduce this issue in a development build?
Yes
Summary
call takePictureAsync and then get the error Received 1 arguments, but 2 was expected.
Happens on iOS, works well on Android.
Using latest versions of expo and expo-camera
"expo": "~51.0.38",
"expo-camera": "~15.0.16",
This issue was created https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/29987 with a fix merged in https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/30103, but I am still getting the issue so I am not sure what to do.
One person commented, "I am experiencing the same on the iOS simulator only. The camera works as expected when running in Expo Go on a physical device, but this seems to be consistent behavior when invoking takePictureAsync on the iOS simulator."
I do not have a physical device to test on currently.
Anyone else running into this / have a solution?

having the same issue, did you find a solution?

I did not. I ended up getting an iPad and it is working on the physical device.
